# Developing a Eclipse: How to get all inherited methods from a ICompilationUnit?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-jdt, pde

How can I find all methods from a ICompilationUnit, including inherited ones, when I am coding a eclipse plugin? When I call the method **getMethods()** there is no inherited methdods.

```
@Override
public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, Object expectedValue) {
    IFile file = (IFile) receiver;
    try {
        IJavaElement element = JavaCore.create(file);
        ICompilationUnit icu = (ICompilationUnit) element;
        IType[] types = icu.getTypes();
        return hasMethodCalledTest(types[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    return false;
}

 public boolean hasMethodCalledTest(IType typeClass) {
     typeClass.getMethods();//There is no inherited method here.
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the soulution using **ITypeHierarchy**

```
IJavaElement element = JavaCore.create(file);
ICompilationUnit icu = (ICompilationUnit) element;
IType[] types = icu.getTypes();
ITypeHierarchy th = types[0].newTypeHierarchy(new NullProgressMonitor());
IType[] superTypes = th.getAllSuperclasses(types[0]);
```